# OSX: Safari: inserting pictures not working

Tags: bug

Drag and drop is not working, inserting with "click here" is working, but only during creating question, not during edit.
The problem is on Safari and MacOS, with chrome it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

This is not appear to be specific to EE. This belongs on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but for some reason, the system is not allowing me to migrate it.

---

Ah. It has already been asked: [Stackoverflow's new image upload does not work on Mac Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317596/222992)